# Is there any way on how to extract the html code from webview to textview without using library

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, text

I want to display an html code from the webview to textview.
Im using sketchware app, I cant install javascriptinterface. Respect post please.

Comment: please post code what you have done so people can know what your problem

Comment: This answer does what your **Question Title** seems to be asking, but it is using the **Android Library**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878485/android-7-webview-with-wrap-content/39955642#39955642